# My dog won't use his new dog door to enter the house without permission

Tags: dogs, training

We recently got a new dog door to replace our two existing dog doors with a stronger flap than our old dog door, and mounted a little higher. We had to teach our two dogs how to use it, alongside a ramp. One of our dogs, three year old Mini-Dachshund, uses it just fine (he was used to ramps).

The other, a 12 year old Jack Russell was a little harder to get onto it. It took a bit of treat therapy. He is now used to the door and ramp, and will use it to go outside at will. But its like he won't enter without permission. He clearly knows how to enter, he enters just fine by himself when called, but he won't enter until we call him. I can call him when I'm in another room and he'll enter (IE he can clearly not see me encouraging him or doing anything beyond voicing his name).

Any advice for how to get him to cease waiting for permission to enter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dog door training: he will go out but won’t come back in!](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/19089/dog-door-training-he-will-go-out-but-won-t-come-back-in)

Comment: How long will the dog wait if you don't give permission? If you let him wait long enough, he might realize he can just go in on his own.